# Extract URL from Excel using VBA not extracting after hash

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, fragment-identifier

I am using the VBA method to extract the URL from a cell:

```
Sub ExtractHL()
Dim HL As Hyperlink
For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
Next
End Sub
```

This is pulling everything in the URL before the # example:
If the whole URL is https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.4.1 my results will only show: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html missing the **#h-24.4.1** Does anyone have a VBA solution to extract the whole URL including the hash and everything after?

Comment: If the only information in the cell is a hyperlink, you can get the whole string with `HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).value = HL.Range.value`

Comment: Do you need to use the hyperlink property? What if you just looped through the values in your sheet and did something like `If InStr(yourString, "https://") Then...` or something like that?

Comment: Don't fully understand what your trying to do if you already have the link.  But `HL.SubAddress` contains the rest of your link.  So `HL.Address & "#" & HL.SubAddress` will rebuild your link (in this case anyways).

Comment: Here is an an example. ![Screenshot includes column A (Hyperlink), Column B (irrelevant), Column C (the extracted hyperlink), below is the Edit Hyperlink box with the whole URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTLAl.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer and explanation on another [site](http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel). The part of the link after the # is regarded as a subaddress. The issue is resolved by including the `.SubAddress`.

```
Function GetURL(cell As range, _
Optional default_value As Variant)
'Lists the Hyperlink Address for a Given Cell
'If cell does not contain a hyperlink, return default_value
If (cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
GetURL = default_value
Else
GetURL = cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address & "#" & cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I could predict where the pound/hash symbol is placed. This is an iterative of another "GetURL" function I found online.

```
Function GetURLs(HyperlinkCell As Range)

    GetURLs = HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address + "#" + HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually create a function. In workbook module paste below function:

```
Function HLink(rng As Range) As String
'extract URL from hyperlink
  If rng(1).Hyperlinks.Count Then HLink = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

Now use the function as a formula, like so:

1. in A1 you have the URL
2. in A2 you have the new formula =hlink(A1)

*PS: original from Rick Rothstein*

Comment: It is still removing everything from from the hashtag on ![Screenshot includes column A (Hyperlink), Column B (irrelevant), Column C (the extracted hyperlink), below is the Edit Hyperlink box with the whole URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTLAl.png)